# Django models for social media apps ValueError in ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am building a social media apps.

This is my models:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class Group(models.Model):
    admin = models.ManyToManyField(Person, related_name='admin')
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=True, related_name='members')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.members.add(self.admin)
        super(Group, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

When i try to create new group, it throws me following error because of overriding `save` method..

ValueError at /admin/social/group/add/

```
"<Group: Group object (None)>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

I want an `admin` of a group also will be a `members` of the same group, that is why i override the save method but it throws me above errors.

Also i tried to achieve this with Django `signal` like below

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Group)
def make_admin_also_members(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.members.add(instance.admin)
        instance.save()
```

and it throws me following error:

```
TypeError at /admin/social/group/add/

int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'ManyRelatedManager'
```

then i try achieve it like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Group)
def make_admin_also_members(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.members.add(str(instance.admin))
        instance.save()
```

it throws me following error:

```
    ValueError at /admin/social/group/add/

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'social.Person.None'
```

After i got above error, i tried to achieve this like below

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Group)
def make_admin_also_members(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.members.add((member.id for member in instance.admin))
        instance.save()
```

I wounded by this error:

```
TypeError at /admin/social/group/add/

'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable
```

and if i try like this below:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Group)
def make_admin_also_members(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.members.add(*instance.admin.all())
        instance.save()
```

It doesn't throws any error but the problem is, it doesn't save the `members` field.

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure `admin` should be a ManyToManyField? Can a group have more than one admin? (If so, at the very least you should call it `admins`.)

Answer (score 0):

It complains that you can not iterate over `instance.admin` itself, only over `instance.admin.all()`

You can use iterable unpacking here, to make adding the persons more convenient. Note that you do *not* have to `instance.save()` if you alter a many-to-many relation, since it is saved in a "hidden" model between the two models.

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Group)
def make_admin_also_members(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.members.add(*instance.admin.all())
```

That being said, if you use a `ModelForm`, it will still not work. Indeed, since a model form will first save the group, and then add the members. So the `post_save` will already been triggered *before* you add the admin members.

So I guess if you did not add the values in the `save(..)` function, and used a `ModelForm`, you should perform the logic in the *view*. So you can define this as:

```
def some_view(request):
    # ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyModelFrom(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            instance.members.add(*instance.admin.all())
    # …
```

Comment: @mamuncode: well then it looks like your `admin` are not saved immediately after you saved the `Group`, which is logical if you used a model form :)

Comment: How? Can help me in this case?

Comment: Later i will serialize Group, so i think modelform will not solve my problem

Comment: @mamuncode: a model form will not *solve* the problems, i'm just saying that the control flow to create objects with m2m relations is to first save the object (and thus trigger a `post_save` as well), and *then* add the m2m items. So the `post_save` trigger is triggered *before* there are any members in `instance.admin`.

Comment: Can you please help me to code it? I never tried of this kind of task...